# How to get ZSH prompt when SSHing

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, homebrew, zsh

I currently have zsh and oh-my-zsh installed with homebrew on my osx workstation. Everything works fine, it is using the correct path (/usr/local/bin/zsh) and changes made in ~/.zshrc such as aliases are working.

My problem is, when I ssh into an ubuntu server, there is no zsh prompt and nothing (zsh related) in ~. Is there something I need to do in order to make zsh work on remote servers?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have zsh installed on the remote ubuntu server?

Comment: Not that I know of... I need to install zsh on every new server I ssh to in order for it to work?

Comment: Install zsh on the remote server and set it as the login shell for the user. If you need help with that, refer to [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: I know I am logging into a different server which is why I said "remote servers". I would appreciate not being patronized. Is there no way to push zsh configs to a remote server on ssh?

Comment: You're right, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install zsh on the remote server (e.g. `apt-get install zsh`)
2. You'll want to push (i.e. `scp -rp`) the following files/directories to the remote server:

   ```
   ~/.zshrc
   ~/.oh-my-zsh/
   ```
3. You'll need to change your remote user's default shell to `zsh` (e.g. run `chsh /bin/zsh` on the remote server)

Comment: More complete instruction [here](https://dev.to/mskian/install-z-shell-oh-my-zsh-on-ubuntu-1804-lts-4cm4)